# Laravel 5.7 Migration : key was too long

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I want to make a multiple unique column, but when i run `php artisan migrate`, i got this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key
> was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

This my code:

```
Schema::create('buku', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('judul');
        $table->string('pengarang');
        $table->string('penerbit');
        $table->string('thn_terbit',4);
        $table->integer('stok');
        $table->string('kategori');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['judul','pengarang','penerbit','thn_terbit'],'unik');
    });
```

this `AppServiceProvider.php` file

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

An answer will be appreciated

Version: Laravel 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]

I solved this by adding a `$table->engine = 'innoDB';` so the code look like this:

```
Schema::create('buku', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'innoDB';

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('judul');
        $table->string('pengarang');
        $table->string('penerbit');
        $table->string('thn_terbit');
        $table->integer('stok');
        $table->string('kategori');
        $table->timestamps();
        
        $table->unique(['judul','pengarang','penerbit','thn_terbit'],'unik');
    });
```

and then re-migrate it, and everything is good.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` file

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

**Note:** The boot method is already there so you just need to add `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` inside it, then delete old tables and re-migrate

Answer (score 0):

You are trying 4 columns for unique index. Sum of 4 columns can be up to 191 characters. Try each column with 47 characters.

```
Schema::create('buku', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'innoDB';

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('judul', 47);
    $table->string('pengarang', 47);
    $table->string('penerbit', 47);
    $table->string('thn_terbit', 47);
    $table->integer('stok');
    $table->string('kategori');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->unique(['judul','pengarang','penerbit','thn_terbit'],'unik');
});
```